# C - error in compilation with references for hardcoded library

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to compile a C program that uses the `libmodbus` library. This library is already installed on the system, that is referenced belong to the `modbus.h`, which is hardcoded this way on the main:

```
#include </usr/include/modbus/modbus.h>
```

The individual compilation produces no errors:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c mbpoll.c
mbpoll.c:186:19: aviso: se define ‘sTcpPortStr’ pero no se usa [-Wunused-const-variable=]
  186 | static const char sTcpPortStr[] = "tcp port";
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
$ gcc -Wall -c custom-rts.c
$ gcc -Wall -c serial.c
```

But the definitive build does:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o myprog mbpoll.o custom-rts.o serial.o 
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.o: en la función `main':
mbpoll.c:(.text+0xde5): referencia a `modbus_new_rtu' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0xe4c): referencia a `modbus_new_tcp_pi' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0xe91): referencia a `modbus_set_debug' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0xeda): referencia a `modbus_rtu_set_serial_mode' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0xef1): referencia a `modbus_rtu_set_rts' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0xf00): referencia a `modbus_connect' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0xf14): referencia a `modbus_free' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0xf22): referencia a `modbus_strerror' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0xfb8): referencia a `modbus_set_response_timeout' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0x109d): referencia a `modbus_set_slave' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0x10e7): referencia a `modbus_write_bit' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0x1108): referencia a `modbus_write_bits' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0x1142): referencia a `modbus_write_register' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0x1164): referencia a `modbus_write_registers' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0x11ba): referencia a `modbus_strerror' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0x1222): referencia a `modbus_set_slave' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0x12f7): referencia a `modbus_read_input_bits' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0x1318): referencia a `modbus_read_bits' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0x1339): referencia a `modbus_read_input_registers' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0x135a): referencia a `modbus_read_registers' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0x13c1): referencia a `modbus_strerror' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.o: en la función `vReportSlaveID':
mbpoll.c:(.text+0x1708): referencia a `modbus_set_slave' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0x178b): referencia a `modbus_report_slave_id' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0x17a8): referencia a `modbus_strerror' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.o: en la función `vSigIntHandler':
mbpoll.c:(.text+0x1e1d): referencia a `modbus_close' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: mbpoll.c:(.text+0x1e2c): referencia a `modbus_free' sin definir
collect2: error: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
```

This references are in `libmodbus` library.

Where is the problem?

Comment: You need to link with the actual library too. Like `-lmodbus` or something

Comment: Append `-lmodbus` to the final gcc invocation.

Comment: @EugeneSh.It works! If you enter it as an answer I will give it for solved

Comment: I think it is a quite frequent duplicate, someone will probably find one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When linking with an external library, you need to pass in the name of the library with the `-l` option:

```
gcc -Wall -o myprog mbpoll.o custom-rts.o serial.o -lmodbus
```